# transform array expression into Object angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i have this json return from http request

```
[
  {
        "player": {
            "1100": {
                "name": "Andy",
                "position": "Keeper"
            },
            "1927": {
                "name": "Cole",
                "position": "benchwarmer"
            },
            "2399": {
                "name": "Derrick",
                "position": "Striker"
            },
            "2900": {
                "name": "Cole",
                "position": "normal supporter"
            }
        },
        "substitutions": [
            {
                "playerin": 1100,
                "playerout": 1927,
                "time": 58
            },
            {
                "playerin": 2399,
                "playerout": 2900,
                "time": 58
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

here is my ts

```
Object = Object;

this.http.get('http://example.com/example.php?matchid='+this.matchId)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => { 
              this.substitutes = res[0].substitutions;
              this.players = res[0].players;


 });
```

while looping the substitutions i would like it to show player name also getting from, i need to change the playerin playerout data into object, but have failed to do so. here is my sample failed code which returns players undefined

```
//failed 1
<div *ngFor="let subH of substitutes">
    {{players[subH.playerin].name}}
    </div> 
//failed 2
<div *ngFor="let subH of Object.keys(substitutes)"> 
    {{players[subH.playerin].name}}
    </div>
```

how can i achieve it ?

Comment: `res` seems to be an array according to your json not an object

Comment: my bad @SurajRao, i have edited it since it was a copy paste edit from original file to simplify it. the problem is i couldn't call players[subH.playerin] since playerin isn't an object yet. that was what i'm thinking probably wrong as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access data from Http in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840878/cant-access-data-from-http-in-ionic-2)

Comment: @SurajRao no it's totally different

Comment: ok can you add _all_ of the relevant code please?

Comment: the id of player : 1100, 1192 is an object thats why im getting undefined when calling   {{players[subH.playerin]?.name}}

Answer (score 0):

```
this.substitutes = res.substitutions;
this.players = res.players;
```

Should be

```
this.substitutes = res[0].substitutions;
this.players = res[0].player;
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkejpe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @PardeepJain my bad, i have edited it since it was a copy paste edit from original file to simplify it. the problem is i couldn't call players[subH.playerin] since playerin isn't an object yet. that was what i'm thinking probably wrong as well

Comment: yes i did..and it is not working on my site....the real file is quite complicated though which consist thousand lines. i have called players[some expression] once before, and it's working...but when i am caling it in another segment it is getting undefined...

Comment: Oh I just posted the answer by seeing your scenario in the question which is working fine in my example

Comment: the ion-segment are on same file same component

Comment: @PardeepJain the id of player : 1100, 1192 is an object thats why im getting undefined when calling   {{players[subH.playerin]?.name}}